# Deleting SitecoreDev.Web, as per the Professional Sitecore 8 Developer book, breaks Sitecore

Tags: installation

I'm on the exercises in chapter 4 and am having issues with cleaning up the webroot.

18.Open File Explorer and navigate to your web root. In the Website folder, open the App_Config\Include folder. Delete the SitecoreDev folder.

19.Now, go to the bin directory in the Website folder and delete the SitecoreDev.Web.* files.

20.Finally, in the Website\Views\Shared folder, delete DefaultMVCLayout.cshtml.

If I delete the SitecoreDev.Web.* files, my Sitecore instance no longer runs.

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: This would be a great question for Sitecore Slack. This really isn't the right place. https://www.akshaysura.com/2015/10/27/how-to-join-sitecore-slack-community-chat/

Answer (score 3):

thanks for reading and working through the book!

I believe the problem is that the `Global.asax` file in your webroot is still inheriting from `SitecoreDev.Web.Application`.  Open this file and make it inherit from `Sitecore.Web.Application`.

```
<%@Application Language='C#' Inherits="Sitecore.Web.Application" %>
```

Let me know if this does not work and I'll dig a little deeper!

Comment: Actually - after further investigation - this did work.  Thanks!